# SharePoint O365 CSOM Web Application with SSO Authentication Service Account

Tags: office-365, csom, sso

So I need to create an Application that will connect to SharePoint Online with a service account Using SSO.

i've downloaded the authentication manager but i don't see any way to code SSO Credentials.

is there a way to have an Service Account or an application impersonating an user?

should i ask my company to provide me with an API to connect through or sso and get the authentication cookie?

Comment: Can I use the step to login sharepoint online on browser?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a service account with username and password, would suggest that you connect and authenticate to SharePoint online by using Client Id and Secret according to this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/development-experience-tenant-apponly-permissions-in-sharepoint-online).

It will be a one-time setup with the below mentioned steps:

1) Go to your SharePoint online site collection

2) Enter the URL as `https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`

3) On that page, we will generate the Client ID and Secret

4) Add the Title as some "SSO Auth"

5) Enter App domain as `localhost` and Redirect URL as `https://localhost`.

6) Then click on create. Save the client ID and Secret in a local file or notepad. It should look something like:

[image]

Once the above step is done, go to `https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`

1) In the App id, enter the Client Id that we generated in the previous step and then click on [lookup]

2) In the Permission Request XML section, enter the below XML code:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

3) Click on [Create]. See below screenshot

[image]

4) After that, it will redirect you and on that page, click on the [Trust It] button.

Once the above steps are done, in your application, download the `SharePoint PnP core` package from nuget as below:

[image]

After that, you can use PnP's Authentication Manager's method to authenticate as below:

```
var clientID = "<your-client-id>";
var clientSecret = "<your-client-secret>";

var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext("https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/test/", clientID, clientSecret);
```

Comment: Thank you Sheth, this work like a Charm !
is there a limit or expiration for the Registered app client ID and Client Secret?

Comment: Client secrets expire after 1 year. After that you renew them which can be extended to 3 years and so on. You can refer [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in)

Comment: Also, there is another way to connect to SharePoint online using `App Only Permissions` and Certificate authentication which can be valid upto 30 years. Its a bit more complicated but you can check out [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/SharePoint.ConnectUsingAppPermissions) sample. Let me know if need the CSOM C# equivalent for this sample !

Comment: can we do same in powershell also?? @GautamSheth

Comment: @RajeshJoshi - you can do that via PnP PowerShell as mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)